# Add bottom and right border to image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add right and bottom border to an image. It should look like this:
[image]

So far, I've got this:
HTML:

```
<div class="img">
<img src="office.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img:before {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #17457A;
 } 

.img:after {
 content: '';
 height: 100%;
 width: 15px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 7;
 top: 15;
 background-color: #17457A;
 }
```

This gives: [image]
The bottom border doesn't even show. Is there a way to have get this exactly like in the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.img-wrap{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.img-wrap > img{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.img-wrap::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Fglennllopis%2Ffiles%2F2018%2F02%2Fshutterstock_1253381451-300x200.jpg" width="400" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `box-shadow` a css property that can act as a border for images, or really any box shape.

If you would like to learn more about it you can visit this link [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

EDIT* Unless you need all your previous CSS for something else, I would just remove it, you should only need the `box-shadow` property.

As for your code here is what you wanted in the blue:

```css
.img img {
  box-shadow: 12px 12px #17457a;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkGCC.png" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use box-shadow instead of border

```
.img {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 1px #ccc;
}
```